# TFSBuild.proj import common targets after getting from source control

Tags: tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild, target

I am currently rewriting/cleaning up our TFS Builds, and I have noticed that we have a lot of duplication. I was wanting to create a "Common.targets" file which all our tfs builds (about 30) would then import.

I have tried a few things along these lines of:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="3.5">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\TeamBuild\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.targets" />
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft.Sdc.Common.Tasks"/>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\MSBuildCommunityTasks\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets"/>

  <Import Project="$(BuildDefinition).proj"/>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <ProjectName>Felix.LincsPublishingHandlers</ProjectName>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Import Project="$(BuildDirectory)/src/BuildScripts/Common/CommonTargets.targets"/>

</Project>
```

Where:

- $(BuildDefinition).proj -> contains project/environment specific properties (eg db connection strings, IP addresses)
- CommonTargets.targets -> used across all the various projects. Defined in the Build Definition > Source Settings

However when I try to run on the TFS Build agent (version 2010 if anyone needs to know), it tries to run the  statements before it has copied down the source files. So I get an error saying that the CommonTargets.targets file doesn't exist.

I've had a look around the web, and the solutions I have come across so far have suggestions that I would prefer not to use:

- Copy the Common.targets file under into the same folder that has the TFSBuild.proj file

  - I have 20+ builds in different folders
  - I would like them all to use a single common.targets file (not 20 copies of the same file)
- Copy the Common.targets file to a location on the build server(s) that the TFS Build Agents can access

  - I want to have it in source control with the rest of the build scripts and code.
  - As we are doing a sort of migration project, the Common.targets will change a bit over time, so best to have in source control

Has come across any similar issue of trying to import a Common.targets file that is kept in TFS source control?

Thanks for any help

Comment: You're on TFS2010. Don't use builds based on MSBuild targets and the Upgrade Template. The MSBuild-based build system was deprecated in TFS2010. It's time to migrate to the "new" (5 year old) build system.

Comment: Just in time for it to be replaced with the new new build system 

Answer (score 0):

First, you should consider upgrading TFS as mainstream support for TFS 2010 ends in a few months.

http://nakedalm.com/its-that-time-again-get-ready-to-upgrade-to-tfs-2015/

Second, you should consider updating your build system to use a modern method. Use the TFS 2013 template and PowerShell.